# Hyper-V VM with public and internal interfaces

Tags: networking, routing, hyper-v

I’m using Hyper-V and having an issue with one of my virtual machines accessing the internet.  The diagram below illustrates the basic configuration:

[image: Diagram]

The host machine has two virtual switches – one "External" and one "Internal".

The external switch has two IP addresses – a primary address, and an alias address which is in a different network range.  The default gateway is in the same network range as the primary IP address.

Virtual Machine 2 (which has only one network adapter, which is on the "Internal" switch and has a class C IP address) has no problem reaching the internet or other VMs on the internal switch.

Virtual Machine 1 has two interfaces:

1. one on the External switch, so that it should be reachable from the internet and uses the host machine's alias IP as the default gateway
2. another interface on the Internal switch to communicate with the other VMs.

The issue I'm having is that Virtual Machine 1 cannot reach the internet. It can ping the other virtual machines on the internal switch without any problem, and it can ping both of the IP addresses of the external switch, but it cannot ping the gateway IP. Packets should go from VM2 to the alias on the host machine (which they do), but then I guess the host machine is preventing the packets from routing to the gateway.

How can I get Virtual Machine 1 to reach the internet?

Comment: (1) Nice diagram! But I have a little trouble reading the yellow text. (2) Have you tried running ```tracert``` (on VM 1)? (3) Have you put a sniffer on the gateway, or between the host and the gateway, to see whether *anything* from VM 1 is getting through?

Comment: I don't understand why your are using the IP address from the physical host as the gateway on the VM guests? What do you have running on the host that is going to route traffic from the guests to the internet for you? As it stands neither VM should be able to reach the internet.

Comment: By the way, you can't have two default gateways on a single machine unless they are redundant routes to the same location.

Comment: @Scott, yes I have tried tracert from VM1 (_192.168.100.3_) to either of the IP's on the host machine (_2.2.2.173_ or _1.1.1.121) and it works fine (only 1 hop).  When I try a tracert to _1.1.1.97_ through (the default gateway of the host machine) it does not work.  The request times out like so:

Tracing route to 1.1.1.97 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: @Appleoddity, the vEthernet Adapter for the Hyper-V "External" switch has ip forwarding enabled.  Is configured as a "Shared" interface (in Windows) so that traffic from the second network adapter (the "Internal" switch) will be routed through it..  There aren't two gateways configured on a single machine.  The host machine has a default gateway of 1.1.1.97 and the virtual machines use default gateway 192.168.100.1.

Comment: (4) Comments don’t handle multi-line text well, and they can disappear.  It’s better to [edit] your question and put all clarifications and additional information there.  (5) I can see what Appleoddity is talking about; your drawing shows that VM 1 adapter 1 has a gateway of 2.2.2.173.

Comment: Ah, I see what Appleoddity is referring to now as well.  It was a mistake in the diagram.  I have updated the diagram to reflect the correct configuration of the machines.

Answer (score 1):

After much messing around, it seems that the issue is that I'm using Windows Server 2012 and apparently Hyper-V doesn't support NAT until version 2016 according to the answer for another question posted here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/821859/configuring-nat-on-a-hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I had to set up Virtual Machine 1 as the gateway for all other virtual machines.